# How to use jquery deferred.then() function?

Tags: jquery, asynchronous

I have a `jquery` website where i make an `asynchronous call` to the *facebook API*.

I need to run a `loading widget` for as long the API is called and after the call is finished hide the widget.

For this reason i decided to use the `deferred.then()` method provided by jquery.

**This is the original asynchronous call that i have**:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            // init the FB JS SDK 
            FB.init({
                appId      : '564984346887426',                                                  // App ID from the app dashboard
                channelUrl : 'channel.html',                                                     // Channel file for x-domain comms
                status     : true,                                                               // Check Facebook Login status
                xfbml      : true                                                                // Look for social plugins on the page
            });
            FB.api('169070991963/albums', checkForErrorFirst(getAlbums));
        }
```

**I try :**

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            // init the FB JS SDK 
            FB.init({
                appId      : '564984346887426',                                                  // App ID from the app dashboard
                channelUrl : 'channel.html',                                                     // Channel file for x-domain comms
                status     : true,                                                               // Check Facebook Login status
                xfbml      : true                                                                // Look for social plugins on the page
            });
            $.mobile.loading("show");
            FB.api('169070991963/albums', checkForErrorFirst(getAlbums))
            .then(
                function(){ $.mobile.loading("hide");
            });
        }
```

but i get the error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined
```

I understand that i am using it wrong. But the examples from the jquery site dont help me much understand how it should be done here. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like `FB.api()` returns `undefined` instead of a promise object. Are you sure it is supposed to return such an object in the first place?

Comment: No i am not sure about that. So if it doesnt return such an object what can i do?

Comment: You would have to use another paradigm (like the callback you apparently pass to `FB.api()`) as a starting point. For instance, you could write a wrapper around `FB.api()` that manages its own deferred object and resolves it during the callback, as Ohgodwhy does in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the deferred object

```
var $df = $.deferred();
```

**Edit** I'm wrong, things have changed, see udpate.

The FB.api accepts a 2nd argument as the callback function to fire when it has been completed.

```
FB.api('169070991963/albums', checkForErrorFirst(getAlbums));
```

Then, in the function checkForErrorFirst(), you'll need to resolve the object

```
function checkForErrorFirst($arg){
    //yuor code
    $df.resolve();
}
```

Then when it's been resolved, it'll fire `.done()` so we supply a callback

```
$df.done(function(){
     alert('resolved');
});
```

Comment: i get the error : Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new b.fn.init(e,t,r)} has no method 'deferred'  in the line : var $df = $.deferred();

Comment: I get the same error again. Its in the line where i declare the variable. I dont think it has something to do with the rest of the code that you updated , even if correctly done. Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: correct me if i am wrong but i think it should be : var $df = new jQuery.Deferred();

Comment: Also the problem is that checkForErrorFirst calls other functions that call her again with different arguments etc etc. That means i have 2-3 API calls nested. How could i wrap it around the first API call , so that when all the calls (including the nested ones) finish , i fire the callback? If i just put it inside the checkForErrorFirst it will fire for the first callback. Imagine that there are 3 nested callbacks all asynchronous that work like one. So i need to wrap it around the first(external) callback.

Comment: @Johny Jaz that would be a problem for a different question.

Comment: It could but as you can see from my question , what i tried from the beginning was to execute a piece of code AFTER the first API call(it doesnt matter that it doesnt work , but that was my question) That means you shouldnt care how many calls would be made inside it. I think i asked the right question here. It just happens that the specific solution that you provide doesnt work in this case. All this imho and respect.